# How do you make the GIMP toolbox have dropdown menus like photoshop? Also, how do you change the format of the splash screen?

Tags: gimp

I am not sure if this is possible, but if anyone knows how to make the gimp toolbox have dropdowns like photoshop, it would be helpful.

An example is that the rectangle select and ellipse select are in one menu, and pressing and holding brings up the different select options.

Also, I would like to change the format of the splash screen. Not the image, but the layout.
This is on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop Down on the toolbox itslef is not implemented in GIMP - and it can't be done by configuration as there is no code for that in place.

While writing the code for that would not be a though thing to do, GIMP is a developer and volunteer starved project - which had decided to hold to some UX sanity on new features - so there had not been a serious discussion on recent years, on how to group tools in the toolbox, and what would be the best way to do it- TL;DR: Don't expect that coming in the near future.

You can, however, choose *which* tools do display on the toolbox - if you have a lot of tools you don't use, that can unclutter it (the other tools will still be accessible by menu/keyboard shortcuts). Just go to `edit->preferences->Tool Box` and mark the ones you want visible.

Your second question is regarding a totally different matter. If you found you just have to replace teh splash image file to have another splash - in non -Windows systems that is all that is needed. I don't have a Windows install to be able to help you - but if there is no indication in gimprc and such files, these dimensions might hace to be set on code as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You are very insightful and helpful, and explain things very well.